# Meaning of curly braces in array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a `.map()` function that changes `isActive` property value of objects in `data` array. However wraps it with curly braces returns me undefined whereas wrapping it with parenthesis or no wrap returns the updated value. Curly braces are used as a wrapper in an arrow function but does it work differently for .map()?

```
    const newData = data.map((data) => {
      data.label === label ? { ...data, isActive: !data.isActive } : data,
    });
    console.log(newData) 
    //undefined



    const newData = data.map((data) => 
      data.label === label ? { ...data, isActive: !data.isActive } : data,
    );
    console.log(newData) 
    //returns updated newData
```

Comment: *"but does it work differently for .map()?"* No. `.map` doesn't know how the function was created, so whether or not you use `.map` has no impact on how the function is interpreted.

Comment: Curly braces are for supporting multiline tasks. If your callback function body has multi-line codes then you have to wrap them in curly braces. And for a map, your must-have to return some value. For a single-line function, you need not use the `return` keyword. It automatically returns the value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That’s the behavior of arrow function. Arrow function syntax is designed to be terse.

```
(arg) => [single expression]
```

If what follows the arrow is one single expression without curly braces, it implies returning the value of that expression. The `return` keyword is omitted.

If wrapping curly braces follows the arrow, then what goes inside the braces are treated as normal function body, and `return` keyword must be used if you mean to return a value.

So `(x) => x + 1` is translated to:

```
function (x) {
  return x + 1;
}
```

And `(x) => { x + 1 }` is translated to:

```
function (x) {
  x + 1;
}
```

I must also add that `(x) => ({ x })` is translated to:

```
function (x) {
  return { x: x };
}
```

Curly brace `{...}` can mean an object literal, a function body or a code block.

In order to disambiguate, you need to put parenthesis around the braces to tell the parser to interpret `{...}` as an “object literal expression”.

Comment: *"The parenthesis around the braces is the syntax for an “object literal expression”"* No. `{...}` is the object literal. The parenthesis tell the parser to interpret `{` as the start of an expression, not an arrow function body.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for correcting me. I’m actually not sure how to phrase it with right word. Would you like to edit my answer directly? I appreciate that.